# Package org.mozilla.interfaces 0.0.0 missing in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, dependencies

I'm trying to install a plugin called textmarker in eclipse. But when i try to install a feature called 'CEV feature', it throws an error saying `requires 'package org.mozilla.interfaces 0.0.0' but it could not be found`. Can anybody let me know how i can resolve this dependency? Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

the package you require is available at 
[link](http://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/xulrunner/releases/1.9.2/sdk/)

download the corrosponding xulrunner according to your machine
extract it and in the folder sdk/lib the jar file is present.

source:
http://code.google.com/p/javaxpcom/wiki/JavaXPCOM_Intro